# How to pick one list out of many based on value in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object structure which looks like this.

```
public class DeliveryManagerQuoteResponse 
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<DeliveryManagerQuotes> Quotes { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryManagerQuotes
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public List<DeliveryManagerQuoteDetails> QuoteDetails { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryManagerQuoteDetails
{
    public string QuoteId { get; set; }
    public int? DeliveryFee { get; set; }
}
```

When I have `DeliveryManagerQuoteResponse` populated, I'll have multiple `Quotes`and each `Quotes` will have multiple `QuoteDetails`. What I want is, based on `DeliveryFee` which in `DeliveryManagerQuoteDetails`, I want to pick the `DeliveryManagerQuoteResponse` which has a minimum delivery fee. How can I do that using LINQ?

I was thinking of getting `DeliveryFee` first from all `Quotes` and then write some code/LINQ to use that to fetch quote with a minimum fee but not sure how to write it :

```
public void PickDeliveryQuoteBasedOnRate(DeliveryManagerQuoteResponse deliveryManagerQuoteResponse)
{

    var feeList = new List<int>();
    foreach (var quote in deliveryManagerQuoteResponse.Quotes)
    {
        if (quote.QuoteDetails != null && quote.QuoteDetails.Any())
        {
            foreach (var quoteDetail in quote.QuoteDetails)
            {
                feeList.Add(quoteDetail.DeliveryFee ?? default(int));
            }
        }
    }

    if (feeList.Any())
    {
        // This will give me minimum fee
        var minimumDeliveryFee = feeList.Min();
        // Need LINQ to use this minimum fee to pick one quote.
    }

}
```

Screen Shot for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: So you want the `DeliveryManagerQuoteDetails` object with the lowest DeliveryFee from a single `DeliveryManagerQuoteResponse` object?

Comment: @maccettura Yes.

Comment: @maccettura I have added screen shot for clear idea.

Comment: DeliveryFee is nullable, would a null value be considered lower than a number?

Comment: I won't consider it. Valid results will have some values (0 is min).

Comment: if 0 is min, then why have a nullable int as your property type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return QuoteDetail with minimum DeliveryFee:

```
deliveryManagerQuoteResponse
.Quotes
.SelectMany(p=>p.QuoteDetails)
.Where(p=>p.DeliveryFee.HasValue)
.Orderby(p=>p.DeliveryFee)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Return Quote With minimum Delivery in it's Detil, So transfering Quote with each QuoteDetail to used it in the last expression for return:

```
deliveryManagerQuoteResponse
  .Quotes
  .SelectMany(p=>p.QuoteDetails.Select(q=>new{Quote=p,Detail=q}))
  .Where(p=>p.Detail.DeliveryFee.HasValue)
  .Orderby(p=>p.Detail.DeliveryFee)
  .FirstOrDefault()?.Quote;
```

Comment: The result of this query is a `DeliveryManagerQuoteDetails`, not a `DeliveryManagerQuotes` as requested by the OP.

Comment: @TaoGómezGil OP specifically asked for a `DeliveryManagerQuoteDetails`.  This answer is correct

Comment: This will throw an error if `QuoteDetails` is null which can be in my case.

Comment: @CSharper how would this throw an error?  The question specifically filters out null values before selecting.  You can see the results yourself [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o46HFo)

Comment: Reza ArabQaeni I downvoted the edit because your first answer was right, also I would suggest you add an explanation to your answer rather than just post code.

Comment: @TaoGómezGil You are right. This will give me `DeliveryManagerQuoteDetails` but I want `DeliveryManagerQuotes`.

Comment: @maccettura, I'm type with mobile so my speed is slow, in continue I write few description.

Comment: @CSharper you need to clarify your post then because you have said many contrary things

Comment: @maccettura I think you misunderstood. Please do not downvote if you do not understand the question. TaoGómezGil understood it clearly.

Comment: @CSharper I asked: "So you want the **DeliveryManagerQuoteDetails** object with the lowest DeliveryFee from a single DeliveryManagerQuoteResponse object?" and you responded: "Yes".  Please tell me how that is not contrary to what you have now said in this comment chain?  Questions where it is _unclear what you are asking_ should be closed.

Comment: No, questions where it is unclear what you are asking should be improved.

Comment: @NetMage very true, I misspoke while trying to convey the reason for my downvote and close vote.  I have commented to the OP why their post was confusing and unclear, gave an opportunity to edit, and added a downvote and a vote to close in the interim.  I will always revoke those when an edit is made to improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pull the detail to the top and then sort through the multiple copies of quotes, I suggest sorting the quotes by the min of all the `DeliveryFee`s:

```
var minDelivery = deliveryManagerQuoteResponse.OrderBy(
                                                  dmqr => dmqr.Quotes // foreach quote
                                                              .SelectMany(q => q.QuoteDetails // foreach QuoteDetail
                                                                                .Where(qd => qd.DeliveryFee.HasValue) // that has a value
                                                                                .Select(qd => qd.DeliveryFee.Value) // select the DeliveryFree
                                                              ) // and flattten the result
                                                              .Min() // and then select the minimum DeliveryFree
                                              ) // sort quotes by minimum DeliveryFee
                                              .FirstOrDefault(); // and select the first quote
```